# Split a string by semicolons while accounting for escaped characters

Tags: c#, string, connection-string

Really simple problem:

I want to split a connection string into its keyword / value pairs, so for example the following connection string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=vm-jp-dev2;Data Source=scsql\sql2005;Auto Translate=False
```

Would become:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1
Integrated Security=SSPI
Persist Security Info=False
Initial Catalog=vm-jp-dev2
Data Source=scsql\sql2005
Auto Translate=False
```

The trouble is that the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) states that connection string values are allowed to contain semicolons if the value is enclosed in single or double quote characters, (so if I understand it the following would be valid):

```
Provider="Some;Provider";Initial Catalog='Some;Catalog';...
```

Whats the best way of splitting this string (in C#)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a DBConnectionStringBuilder class that will do what you want...

```
        System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();

        builder.ConnectionString = "Provider=\"Some;Provider\";Initial Catalog='Some;Catalog';";

        foreach (string key in builder.Keys)
        {
            Response.Write(String.Format("{0}: {1}<br>", key , builder[key]));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be something like this but I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement some sort of simple string parsing respecing quotes. Something like that:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string str)
{
    int StartIndex = 0;
    bool IsQuoted = false;
    for (int I = 0; I < str.Length; I++)
    {
        if (str[I] == '"')
            IsQuoted = !IsQuoted;
        if ((str[I] == ';') && !IsQuoted)
        {
            yield return str.Substring(StartIndex, I - StartIndex);        
            StartIndex = I + 1;
        }
    }

    if (StartIndex < str.Length)
        yield return str.Substring(StartIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a mini-parser. Moves through the string keeping track of the quoting state. Likely more reliable in general.

The other option is to use a regular expression, and match the whole content, which can be captured in a `regex.Split` rather than skipping the output:

```
var re = new Regex(@"([\w\s]+=\s*?(?:['""][\w\s]+['""]|[\w\s]+));");
var parts = re.Split(connectionString)
```

This assumes:

- No ability to quote quotes inside quotes (or otherwise)
- Content on names is limited to white space and alpha-numerics (replace [\s\w] with group that covers valid characters).

Personally if I couldn't workout the regex quite quickly I'd go with the parser.

EDIT: There is an easier way. `DbConnectionStringBuilder` implements `IEnumerable`, so get it to do the work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string conStr = @"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=vm-jp-dev2;Data Source='scsql\sql;2005';Auto Translate=False";

        var cb = new DbConnectionStringBuilder();
        cb.ConnectionString = conStr;
        int n = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> c in cb) {
            Console.WriteLine("#{0}: {1}={2}", ++n, c.Key, c.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of SQL Server you can do simply:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder decoder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

string UserID = decoder.UserID; 
string Password = decoder.Password;
```

etc.